# How to Capitalize the first letter of each String seperated by whitespace in java

Tags: java

Ok, I already have the code written and solved. My problem is when I input two words on the same line I get the output of what I have Inputted along with the solution that I want.

I get this output. [image]

I would like this output instead....      happy thursday

```
                             Happy Thursday
```

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterCapitalize {

    String CapitalizeLetter(String str) {

        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        String string = " ";

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            char letter = Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0));
            string = " " + letter+ words[i].substring(1);
            str += string;
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner  s = new Scanner(System.in);
         LetterCapitalize c = new LetterCapitalize();
         System.out.print(c. CapitalizeLetter(s.nextLine())); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `str += string;` does?

Answer (score 1):

The following can fix it.reinitialize str to empty string.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

 public class LetterCapitalize {

    String CapitalizeLetter(String str) {

    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    String string = " ";
   //re initialize to empty string
    str="";
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        char letter = Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0));
        string = " " + letter+ words[i].substring(1);
        str += string;
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner  s = new Scanner(System.in);
     LetterCapitalize c = new LetterCapitalize();
     System.out.print(c. CapitalizeLetter(s.nextLine()));
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external library, I would try `capitalize` in [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) library.

Comment: Thanks, I just learned something. I appreciate your help..@cacho

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the `str` to empty or use new string variable. because it is containing the input string already.

   ```
   str = "";
   ```
2. Don't add space along with letter `capitalization`. That way, you will end up with extra space in the front of the output. Add the space, when your `output string` length is more then zero, which mean it contains some strings already. This should be the first thing in for loop, otherwise you will get extra space in end of the string.

   ```
   if (str.length() > 0) {
     str = str + " ";
   }
   ```

Here is the code:

```
public class LetterCapitalize {
  String CapitalizeLetter(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    String string;
    str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (str.length() > 0) {
        str = str + " ";
      }
      char letter = Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0));
      string = letter+ words[i].substring(1);
      str += string;
    }
    return str;
  }
}
```